# get Azure VM hardware profile via Azure Python SDK

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to develop a system parameter optimization algorithm on Azure but I'm stuck in an API question.

I can use azure cli command to get a VM hardware profile but I can't figure out which Azure SDK API has equivalent result.

Azure cli command and partial output result is:

```
az vm get-instance-view -g GROUP_NAME -n VM_NAME.
```

output will include:

```
"hardwareProfile": {
     "vmSize": "Standard_D4s_v3"
 },
```

The value of vmSize is what I need. I tried with:

```
compute_client.virtual_machines.get(GROUP_NAME, VM_NAME, expand='instanceView').instance_view
```

but I couldn't get expected result from above API. I have searched but failed to find out from Azure doc either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make it clear. It's not weird.

In your first method, you define the `expand='instanceView'`, which can only return the instance view of a virtual machine. And instance view means information about the run-time state of a virtual machine. It(the instance view) does not contain the VM hardware profile information.

You can use this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/instanceview)(the `get()` method also calls this api when you go through the source code) to check the returned result for instance view, like below:

[image]

And if you does not specify the instanceview in the get() method, it will return the model view of a vm, which contains VM hardware profile information.

You can also test it via this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get) for model view of a vm.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

found out after I posted this question, weird:

```
virtual_machine = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(
        GROUP_NAME,
        VM_NAME
    )
hardware = virtual_machine.hardware_profile
print("\nHardware:", hardware)
```

output is:

```
hardware: {'additional_properties': {}, 'vm_size': 'Standard_D2s_v3'}
```